# What is the meaning of the second + in the save file?

Tags: the-witness

in the "Load a Game" menu it tells you how many puzzles you solved in this format:
("normal" puzzles ) SOLVED, +(environmental puzzles) +(the number in question); ...
so what does this second + with the number refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this IGN article](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/Easy_to_Miss_Puzzles), the second number is the number of solved puzzles that do not involve panels.

> Here's the number that a 100% game file should have, as far as current
>   players are aware of:
>
> 523 +135 +6
>
> The first number represents puzzles solved, the second number
>   represents environmental puzzles completed, and the third number
>   represents obelisks completed by finding all the associated
>   environmental puzzles.